# INSERT INTO target table new entry for each column within a row of source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-insert, unpivot

I'm sorry if the title is confusing. I have a **very large** source table that is structured somewhat like this

```
From Mile  | To Mile |
           |         |From Weight| 1000       | 1100 | 1200 | 1300... | 22500 | 23000
           |         |To Weight  | 1099       | 1199 | 1299 | 1499... | 22999 | 23499
==========================================================================
     1     |   20    |           | 1500       | 1505 | 1489 | 1854... | 3400  | 2990
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     21    |   40    |           | 1400       | 1705 | 491  | 5581... | 1600  | 2989
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     41    |   60    |           | 1800       | 1635 | 1982 | 1888... | 3200  | 3480
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where one can pick a certain milage, e.g. 23, and a certain weight, e.g. 1250, and get a "rate" - in this case, 491.

```
From Mile  | To Mile |
           |         |From Weight|            |      | 1200 |         |       |
           |         |To Weight  |            |      | 1299 |         |       | 
==========================================================================
           |         |           |            |      |      |     ... |       | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     21    |   40    |           |            |      | 491  |     ... |       | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
           |         |           |            |      |      |     ... |       | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would want to insert each rate with their corresponding weight and mile ranges.

```
Id   | Mile_To | Mile_From | Weight_To | Weight_From | Rate
===========================================================
0    | 1       | 20        | 1000      | 1099        | 1500
-----------------------------------------------------------
1    | 1       | 20        | 1100      | 1199        | 1505
-----------------------------------------------------------
2    | 1       | 20        | 1200      | 1299        | 1389
-----------------------------------------------------------
3    | 1       | 20        | 1300      | 1499        | 1854
-----------------------------------------------------------
...
-----------------------------------------------------------
40   | 1       | 20        | 22500     | 22999       | 3400
-----------------------------------------------------------
41   | 1       | 20        | 23000     | 23499       | 2990
-----------------------------------------------------------
42   | 21      | 40        | 1000      | 1199        | 1400
```

What is the best way to step through the source table and insert the data as formatted above? There around hundreds of rows and columns, so naming each one would be similar to manually entering the data.

Here is a SQLFiddle with an example of the source table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48777a/1

Comment: I won't work up a full answer but here's a hint: use CROSS JOIN to generate the table.  If the "weight categories" are as predictable as in the example (steps of 1000), you can probably generate a sequence of weight categories, generate a sequence of mile categories, and CROSS JOIN those to create your result table.  The only complicated part is filling in the "rate" column, which is going to be a fairly ugly JOIN to the source table.

Comment: @workerjoe Thank you for the help, there is an CROSS JOIN answer posted below that worked out great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` to unpivot this dataset:

```
select 
    s.from_miles,
    s.to_miles,
    x.*
from source s
cross apply (values
    (1000, 1099, s.[1000_to_1099]),
    (1100, 1199, s.[1100_to_1199]),
    (1200, 1299, s.[1200_to_1299]),
    (1300, 1399, s.[1300_to_1399]),
    (1400, 1499, s.[1400_to_1499])
) as x(weight_from, weigh_to, rate)
```

You can easily turn this to an `insert` statement:

```
insert into newtable (from_moles, to_moles, weight_from, weight_to, rate)
select ... -- above query
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I knew there had to be a simpler way to do this! The original code was 16,000 lines if you can believe it.

Comment: I rewrotei an 800-line scripts with a single-page `merge` once. 16K lines is ridiculous though!